# How do I find specific event in data series?

Tags: python, time-series

I have a series of data files containing an analog signal recording.  It has 2 columns, time and voltage.  There is a specific event and I would like to find the exact time that it happens or begins.  Most of the data is pretty smooth, but then there is a huge EM spike, where the data is about 10x higher than the rest of them.  I want to find the time when the spike happens, how can I do that?   I have a LOT of files and they are too big for excel so I need to find another way to extract the parts I need.

I figured it would be easiest to just find the values > some threshold, but the spike covers such a wide index range and I want to be precise so I just want to isolate the beginning of it.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
% time          index           chan. 1       
-9.993680E-002  -1.249210E+005  -1.351950E-003
-9.993600E-002  -1.249200E+005  -1.416387E-003
-9.993520E-002  -1.249190E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.993440E-002  -1.249180E+005  -1.255296E-003
-9.993360E-002  -1.249170E+005  -1.319732E-003
-9.993280E-002  -1.249160E+005  -1.094204E-003
-9.993200E-002  -1.249150E+005  -1.094204E-003
-9.993120E-002  -1.249140E+005  -9.331130E-004
-9.993040E-002  -1.249130E+005  -1.287514E-003
-9.992960E-002  -1.249120E+005  -1.029768E-003
-9.992880E-002  -1.249110E+005  -1.480823E-003
-9.992800E-002  -1.249100E+005  -1.061986E-003
-9.992720E-002  -1.249090E+005  -1.126423E-003
-9.992640E-002  -1.249080E+005  -9.653312E-004
-9.992560E-002  -1.249070E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.992480E-002  -1.249060E+005  -9.975495E-004
-9.992400E-002  -1.249050E+005  -1.448605E-003
-9.992320E-002  -1.249040E+005  -1.255296E-003
-9.992240E-002  -1.249030E+005  -1.094204E-003
-9.992160E-002  -1.249020E+005  -1.480823E-003
-9.992080E-002  -1.249010E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.992000E-002  -1.249000E+005  -1.255296E-003
-9.991920E-002  -1.248990E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.991840E-002  -1.248980E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.991760E-002  -1.248970E+005  -1.319732E-003
-9.991680E-002  -1.248960E+005  -1.223077E-003
-9.991600E-002  -1.248950E+005  -1.223077E-003
-9.991520E-002  -1.248940E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.991440E-002  -1.248930E+005  -9.008947E-004
-9.991360E-002  -1.248920E+005  -1.158641E-003
-9.991280E-002  -1.248910E+005  -1.126423E-003
-9.991200E-002  -1.248900E+005  -1.190859E-003
-9.991120E-002  -1.248890E+005  -1.255296E-003
-9.991040E-002  -1.248880E+005  -1.577478E-003
-9.990960E-002  -1.248870E+005  -1.641915E-003
```

The 3rd column is what I'm interested in.  The sampling rate is high (1MHz), so the sharp rise could cover up to 1000 points.

Comment: 1) Could you paste a snippet of your data file so we know what kind of data we're dealing with?

2) In the context of the data you post, provide us with a sample output of what you want from the code.

Comment: If it's really obvious, you can go through the data and do something like `value[x+1] - value[x] > threshold`, or slightly more elaborate if necessary. If not, look for signal detection methods. [Wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) might work, and they are available in Scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

Comment: thanks Paulo I'm gonna try this method